# What quotes happen when Ezra is in the World Between Worlds?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

From what I’ve made out by watching “World Between Worlds”, I heard

“Help me Obi-Wan, Your my only hope” -Leia ANH

And, “I lost my way for a long time. But now, I have a chance to change things.” – Kanan Rebels

I heard fragments of a lot more, but couldn’t make them out. Is there a list of the quotes/lines/dialogue from the World Between Worlds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (fan-run) YouTube account [Star Wars Explained](https://www.youtube.com/@StarWarsExplained) has a [video edit of the World Between Worlds scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eyymBDBOcr0), overlaying the footage of the film/TV sources of each line with the audio as heard in the episode:

In order, these are:

> YODA: "Truly wonderful the mind of a child is." <sub>(Attack of the Clones)</sub>
>
> OBI-WAN KENOBI: "What is this place?" <sub>(The Clone Wars: Overlords)</sub>
>
> QUI-GON JINN: "A conduit through which the entire Force of the universe flows." <sub>(The Clone Wars: Overlords)</sub>
>
> YODA: "Luminous beings are we, not this crude matter." <sub>(The Empire Strikes Back)</sub>
>
> AHSOKA TANO: "Just when you think you understand the Force, you find out how little you actually know." <sub>(Rebels)</sub>
>
> YODA: "Train yourself to let go of everything you fear to lose." <sub>(Revenge of the Sith)</sub>
>
> BEN KENOBI: "What you need, you already have. Unfortunately, you seem to be letting it all go." <sub>(Rebels: Twin Suns)</sub>
>
> KANAN JARRUS: "I won't let him lose his way. Not like I did." <sub>(Rebels: Path of the Jedi)</sub>
>
> BEN KENOBI: "The Force is what gives a Jedi his power. It's an energy field created by all living things. It surrounds us and penetrates us. It binds the galaxy together." <sub>(A New Hope)</sub>
>
> YODA: "Rejoice for those around you who transform into the Force." <sub>(Revenge of the Sith)</sub>
>
> MAZ KANATA: "I see your eyes. You already know the truth." <sub>(The Force Awakens)</sub>
>
> CHIRRUT ÎMWE: "I'm one with the Force, the Force is with me." <sub>(Rogue One)</sub>
>
> JYN ERSO: "The time to fight is now!" <sub>(Rogue One)</sub>
>
> KYLO REN: "Show me..." <sub>(The Force Awakens)</sub>
>
> REY: "We'll see each other again." <sub>(The Force Awakens)</sub>
>
> KYLO REN: "... Grandfather." <sub>(The Force Awakens)</sub>
>
> REY: "I believe that." <sub>(The Force Awakens)</sub>
>
> KYLO REN: "Then I will finish..." <sub>(The Force Awakens)</sub>
>
> ANAKIN SKYWALKER: "I won't lose you, Padmé." <sub>(Revenge of the Sith)</sub>
>
> KYLO REN: "... what you started." <sub>(The Force Awakens)</sub>
>
> POE DAMERON: "[The Resistance] will not be intimidated by you." <sub>(The Force Awakens)</sub>
>
> DAUGHTER: "It is his nature." <sub>(The Clone Wars: Altar of Mortis)</sub>
>
> MAZ KANATA: "The belonging you seek is not behind you." <sub>(The Force Awakens)</sub>
>
> LEIA ORGANA: "This is our most desperate hour." <sub>(A New Hope)</sub>
>
> YODA: "The shadow of greed that is." <sub>(Revenge of the Sith)</sub>
>
> LEIA: "Help me, Obi-Wan Kenobi. You're my only hope." <sub>(A New Hope)</sub>
>
> YODA: "Let go of everything you fear to lose." <sub>(Revenge of the Sith)</sub>
>
> ANAKIN SKYWALKER: "You never would have made it as Obi-Wan's padawan. But you might make it as mine." <sub>(The Clone Wars (film))</sub>
>
> DARTH VADER: "Obi-Wan once thought as you do." <sub>(The Empire Strikes Back)</sub>
>
> DARTH VADER: "You don't know the power of the dark side." <sub>(The Empire Strikes Back)</sub>
>
> <sub>(Source: Captions transcript on [The Voices in A World Between Worlds (SPOILERS)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eyymBDBOcr0), edited with speaker and source attributions)</sub>